# How do I correctly re-edit htaccess to become visible to search?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Been screwing around with htaccess in order to hide the .html from the end of the URLS. Now, the site is invisible to all search engines, even when using site:url to search the domain directly. What's causing it?

```
# Use PHP5.6 as default
# AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "0"
    Header set X-nginx-cache "WordPress"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Search engines don't suddenly forget the references to your site just because you block their robots. Are you sure that things worked before?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Turns out some search engines (DuckDuckGo, Ecosia, Bing) are not displaying the site anywhere, while others (Google) are. Probably not related to htaccess after all.

Comment: Different search engines use different robots. If you announce your site only to Google, then obviously other search engines will only find your site much later or not at all.

Comment: "invisible to all search engines" - Not crawlable by search engines or just not indexed by search engines? There's nothing in the `.htaccess` file you posted that would affect this. However, questions related to search engines and SEO are off-topic at StackOverflow. It could be on-topic at [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but as it stands this question is not answerable - there could be any number of reasons why your site is not indexed. What did you do exactly? Was the site previously indexed? etc.

Comment: It appears as though some search engines are simply not returning searches where the site url is the search term. Bing, Ecosia, DuckDuckGo. Correct, it's nothing to do with htaccess apparently. Given that this is an SEO question (noted), I'll abandon inquiry here and search elsewhere. Thanks for your help MrWhite.